# unable to connect to R from c#

Tags: c#, r

I am trying to connect to R from c# using the following code. It looks like C# is not reading the R dll files. My R installation directory is this:

```
C:\Users\R-2-13\R-2.13.0\bin\i386
```

and I also downloaded and put the R.NET.dll in the same directory. In Visual Studio, I set the reference to R.NET.dll file. When I run the following code, the code goes the the catch section "unable to find the R Installation". Any ideas? Has anybody got this working?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDotNet;

namespace RNet_Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        // set up basics and create RDotNet instance 
        // if anticipated install of R is not found, ask the user to find it. 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            bool r_located = false;
            while (r_located == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    REngine.SetDllDirectory(@"C:\Users\R-2-13\R-2.13.0\bin\i386");
                    REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet"); 
                    r_located = true;
                }

                catch { MessageBox.Show(@"Unable to find R installation's \bin\i386 folder. Press OK to attempt to locate it."); 

                        MessageBox.Show("error");

                } 
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a question why do try to connect R from c#? Can give us the context ?

Comment: I would like to design a page that will have user controls. Provided the user controls, I need to post back charts. Can I post pack charts from R to front end?

Comment: it is a web page? asp.net ? or what ? you can run a script , save plots as png and display them..I assume you can display png pictures..

Comment: @agstudy, I already did that it works. But users want user controls. For example, let's say there is data frame that has dates. they want to be able to pick dates and create charts on demand.

Comment: It is a web application?  you can run script on demand it is really fast ..

Comment: yes, ultimately it will be web application. I was trying to use form to get connected to R, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

This is http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/ (RDotNet) to develop Winform applications. While I know Shiny and all the other Web-like R-tools quite well, the combination of c# and R still is my preferred end-user combinations. Try simple things like disabling buttons with Shiny...

Too bad rdotnet is quite buggy; in the current version, it crashes on R exeptions, even in try-catched ones.

This said: please make absolutely sure that you use version 1.5, not the stupidly called "stable" (=early beta) version on the page. Best download it via NuGet. Also check if you did not mix 32bit R with 64 bit c#.

Using the Helper-functions of 1.5, initialization is:

```
  Helper.SetEnvironmentVariables();
  engine = REngine.CreateInstance(EngineName);
  engine.Initialize();
  # Assuming you want to catch the graphic window, use my RGraphAppHook
  # on the rdotnet site http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7
  cbt = new RGraphAppHook { GraphControl = GraphPanelControl };
```

Comment: +1! for the shiny buttons!  did you try rpy2? I thing is is the most mature solution for R web application.

Comment: @Dieter Menne, I really appreciate this. I dont see any r.net verion 1.5, do you have direct link the download?

Comment: @agstudy: rpy2 ? Got lost in installation space under Windows 64 bit.

Comment: I used it only with linux so I can't say anything under windows.. I am preety sure that @lgautier can help better here...